# Что то не так с json вопрос на php

Tags: php

Почему этот код не декодируется в json делаю так:

```
$json = 'jsonp1776({"rateDetail":{"rateCount":{"total":14,"shop":0,"picNum":5,"used":1},"rateDanceInfo":{"storeType":4,"currentMilles":1540722083967,"showChooseTopic":false,"intervalMilles":24472088538},"rateList":[{"auctionPicUrl":"","userInfo":"","displayRatePic":"","dsr":0,"displayRateSum":0,"appendComment":null,"fromMemory":0,"picsSmall":[],"tmallSweetPic":"","rateDate":"2018-10-23 09:17:05","rateContent":"浠婂ぉ涔熸槸绌挎潵鍝ュ悓娆剧殑涓€澶 鍢诲樆 寮€蹇 閴村畾杩囨槸姝ｅ搧鍟?,"fromMall":true,"userIdEncryption":"","sellerId":3329658704,"displayUserLink":"","id":1021711195318,"aliMallSeller":false,"reply":"","pics":["//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/i1/O1CN0128PhI3WWMbIKcx0_!!0-rate.jpg","//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/i4/O1CN0128PhI3mQz3Gh9DM_!!0-rate.jpg"],"buyCount":0,"userVipLevel":0,"auctionSku":"棰滆壊:榛勮壊;灏虹爜:S[缇庣増鍋忓ぇ]","anony":false,"displayUserNumId":0,"goldUser":false,"attributesMap":null,"tradeEndTime":{"date":14,"hours":19,"seconds":58,"month":9,"timezoneOffset":-480,"year":118,"minutes":8,"time":1539515338000,"day":0},"headExtraPic":"","aucNumId":0,"displayUserNick":"涓?**n","structuredRateList":[],"carServiceLocation":"","userVipPic":"","serviceRateContent":"","memberIcon":"","attributes":"","position":"","cmsSource":"澶╃尗","tamllSweetLevel":0,"gmtCreateTime":{"date":23,"hours":9,"seconds":5,"month":9,"timezoneOffset":-480,"year":118,"minutes":17,"time":1540257425000,"day":2},"useful":true,"displayUserRateLink":""},{"auctionPicUrl":"","userInfo":"","displayRatePic":"","dsr":0,"displayRateSum":0,"appendComment":null,"fromMemory":0,"picsSmall":[],"tmallSweetPic":"","rateDate":"2018-10-19 00:40:09","rateContent":"鍒板簳鏄編鐗?hellip;璐ㄩ噺涓嶆暍鎭淮馃槀鍛婅緸 173涔扮殑l oversize椋 琚栧瓙涔熷ぇ澶х殑 鍠滄馃挄","fromMall":true,"userIdEncryption":"","sellerId":3329658704,"displayUserLink":"","id":1021036217099,"aliMallSeller":false,"reply":"","pics":["//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/i4/O1CN011IQHmHIY5Rh81tk_!!0-rate.jpg"],"buyCount":0,"userVipLevel":0,"auctionSku":"棰滆壊:鐧借壊;灏虹爜:L[缇庣増鍋忓ぇ]","anony":false,"displayUserNumId":0,"goldUser":false,"attributesMap":null,"tradeEndTime":{"date":19,"hours":0,"seconds":17,"month":9,"timezoneOffset":-480,"year":118,"minutes":37,"time":1539880637000,"day":5},"headExtraPic":"","aucNumId":0,"displayUserNick":"鏉?**i","structuredRateList":[],"carServiceLocation":"","userVipPic":"","serviceRateContent":"","memberIcon":"","attributes":"","position":"","cmsSource":"澶╃尗","tamllSweetLevel":0,"gmtCreateTime":{"date":19,"hours":0,"seconds":9,"month":9,"timezoneOffset":-480,"year":118,"minutes":40,"time":1539880809000,"day":5},"useful":true,"displayUserRateLink":""},{"auctionPicUrl":"","userInfo":"","displayRatePic":"","dsr":0,"displayRateSum":0,"appendComment":null,"fromMemory":0,"picsSmall":[],"tmallSweetPic":"","rateDate":"2018-10-14 12:02:06","rateContent":"缇庣編鍝 nice","fromMall":true,"userIdEncryption":"","sellerId":3329658704,"displayUserLink":"","id":1020457913554,"aliMallSeller":false,"reply":"","pics":["//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/i3/O1CN012FLInTdIwS84gEx_!!0-rate.jpg"],"buyCount":0,"userVipLevel":0,"auctionSku":"棰滆壊:鐧借壊;灏虹爜:M[缇庣増鍋忓ぇ]","anony":false,"displayUserNumId":0,"goldUser":true,"attributesMap":null,"tradeEndTime":{"date":14,"hours":11,"seconds":38,"month":9,"timezoneOffset":-480,"year":118,"minutes":56,"time":1539489398000,"day":0},"headExtraPic":"","aucNumId":0,"displayUserNick":"y***3","structuredRateList":[],"carServiceLocation":"","userVipPic":"","serviceRateContent":"","memberIcon":"","attributes":"","position":"","cmsSource":"澶╃尗","tamllSweetLevel":0,"gmtCreateTime":{"date":14,"hours":12,"seconds":6,"month":9,"timezoneOffset":-480,"year":118,"minutes":2,"time":1539489726000,"day":0},"useful":true,"displayUserRateLink":""},{"auctionPicUrl":"","userInfo":"","displayRatePic":"","dsr":0,"displayRateSum":0,"appendComment":null,"fromMemory":0,"picsSmall":[],"tmallSweetPic":"","rateDate":"2018-10-19 13:22:45","rateContent":"寰堣垝鏈 nice 瀹㈡湇鍛 灏辨槸鏈夌偣鍌 浜鸿繕铔ソ鐨?,"fromMall":true,"userIdEncryption":"","sellerId":3329658704,"displayUserLink":"","id":1021011044589,"aliMallSeller":false,"reply":"","pics":[],"buyCount":0,"userVipLevel":0,"auctionSku":"棰滆壊:钘忛潚鑹丙灏虹爜:XL[缇庣増鍋忓ぇ]","anony":false,"displayUserNumId":0,"goldUser":false,"attributesMap":null,"tradeEndTime":{"date":19,"hours":13,"seconds":17,"month":9,"timezoneOffset":-480,"year":118,"minutes":22,"time":1539926537000,"day":5},"headExtraPic":"","aucNumId":0,"displayUserNick":"鑻?**5","structuredRateList":[],"carServiceLocation":"","userVipPic":"","serviceRateContent":"","memberIcon":"","attributes":"","position":"","cmsSource":"澶╃尗","tamllSweetLevel":0,"gmtCreateTime":{"date":19,"hours":13,"seconds":45,"month":9,"timezoneOffset":-480,"year":118,"minutes":22,"time":1539926565000,"day":5},"useful":true,"displayUserRateLink":""},{"auctionPicUrl":"","userInfo":"","displayRatePic":"","dsr":0,"displayRateSum":0,"appendComment":null,"fromMemory":0,"picsSmall":[],"tmallSweetPic":"","rateDate":"2018-10-17 21:44:56","rateContent":"鐮佹暟鍒氬垰濂斤紝娆惧紡鎸哄悎閫傜埍娼殑鎴戯紝澶枩娆簡","fromMall":true,"userIdEncryption":"","sellerId":3329658704,"displayUserLink":"","id":1020983138960,"aliMallSeller":false,"reply":"","pics":[],"buyCount":0,"userVipLevel":0,"auctionSku":"棰滆壊:鐧借壊;灏虹爜:M[缇庣増鍋忓ぇ]","anony":false,"displayUserNumId":0,"goldUser":false,"attributesMap":null,"tradeEndTime":{"date":17,"hours":21,"seconds":38,"month":9,"timezoneOffset":-480,"year":118,"minutes":43,"time":1539783818000,"day":3},"headExtraPic":"","aucNumId":0,"displayUserNick":"c***6","structuredRateList":[],"carServiceLocation":"","userVipPic":"","serviceRateContent":"","memberIcon":"","attributes":"","position":"","cmsSource":"澶╃尗","tamllSweetLevel":0,"gmtCreateTime":{"date":17,"hours":21,"seconds":56,"month":9,"timezoneOffset":-480,"year":118,"minutes":44,"time":1539783896000,"day":3},"useful":true,"displayUserRateLink":""},{"auctionPicUrl":"","userInfo":"","displayRatePic":"","dsr":0,"displayRateSum":0,"appendComment":null,"fromMemory":0,"picsSmall":[],"tmallSweetPic":"","rateDate":"2018-10-18 07:57:33","rateContent":"寰堝枩娆紝璐ㄩ噺涔熸尯濂界殑","fromMall":true,"userIdEncryption":"","sellerId":3329658704,"displayUserLink":"","id":1020923181934,"aliMallSeller":false,"reply":"","pics":[],"buyCount":0,"userVipLevel":0,"auctionSku":"棰滆壊:鐧借壊;灏虹爜:S[缇庣増鍋忓ぇ]","anony":false,"displayUserNumId":0,"goldUser":false,"attributesMap":null,"tradeEndTime":{"date":17,"hours":19,"seconds":4,"month":9,"timezoneOffset":-480,"year":118,"minutes":12,"time":1539774724000,"day":3},"headExtraPic":"","aucNumId":0,"displayUserNick":"t***4","structuredRateList":[],"carServiceLocation":"","userVipPic":"","serviceRateContent":"","memberIcon":"","attributes":"","position":"","cmsSource":"澶╃尗","tamllSweetLevel":0,"gmtCreateTime":{"date":18,"hours":7,"seconds":33,"month":9,"timezoneOffset":-480,"year":118,"minutes":57,"time":1539820653000,"day":4},"useful":true,"displayUserRateLink":""},{"auctionPicUrl":"","userInfo":"","displayRatePic":"","dsr":0,"displayRateSum":0,"appendComment":null,"fromMemory":0,"picsSmall":[],"tmallSweetPic":"","rateDate":"2018-10-13 12:18:53","rateContent":"璋㈣阿搴椾富铏惧摜缁欐垜浠嬬粛鐨勫瘜濠嗐€傛槰澶╁ス鍏崄澶у 杩橀€佹垜涓€杈嗛鐏€傝醇甯呯殑","fromMall":true,"userIdEncryption":"","sellerId":3329658704,"displayUserLink":"","id":1020339153220,"aliMallSeller":false,"reply":"","pics":[],"buyCount":0,"userVipLevel":0,"auctionSku":"棰滆壊:娴呯伆鑹丙灏虹爜:M[缇庣増鍋忓ぇ]","anony":false,"displayUserNumId":0,"goldUser":false,"attributesMap":null,"tradeEndTime":{"date":13,"hours":12,"seconds":40,"month":9,"timezoneOffset":-480,"year":118,"minutes":17,"time":1539404260000,"day":6},"headExtraPic":"","aucNumId":0,"displayUserNick":"d***4","structuredRateList":[],"carServiceLocation":"","userVipPic":"","serviceRateContent":"","memberIcon":"","attributes":"","position":"","cmsSource":"澶╃尗","tamllSweetLevel":0,"gmtCreateTime":{"date":13,"hours":12,"seconds":53,"month":9,"timezoneOffset":-480,"year":118,"minutes":18,"time":1539404333000,"day":6},"useful":true,"displayUserRateLink":""},{"auctionPicUrl":"","userInfo":"","displayRatePic":"","dsr":0,"displayRateSum":0,"appendComment":null,"fromMemory":0,"picsSmall":[],"tmallSweetPic":"","rateDate":"2018-09-14 14:59:22","rateContent":"璐ㄩ噺涓嶉敊寰堝枩娆紝闈㈡枡鎽歌捣鏉ヤ篃寰堣垝鏈嶏紝寰堜紤闂层€?,"fromMall":true,"userIdEncryption":"","sellerId":3329658704,"displayUserLink":"","id":1017059707738,"aliMallSeller":false,"reply":"","pics":[],"buyCount":0,"userVipLevel":0,"auctionSku":"棰滆壊:鐏拌壊;灏虹爜:M[缇庣増鍋忓ぇ]","anony":false,"displayUserNumId":0,"goldUser":false,"attributesMap":null,"tradeEndTime":{"date":12,"hours":1,"seconds":44,"month":8,"timezoneOffset":-480,"year":118,"minutes":52,"time":1536688364000,"day":3},"headExtraPic":"","aucNumId":0,"displayUserNick":"t***7","structuredRateList":[],"carServiceLocation":"","userVipPic":"","serviceRateContent":"","memberIcon":"","attributes":"","position":"","cmsSource":"澶╃尗","tamllSweetLevel":0,"gmtCreateTime":{"date":14,"hours":14,"seconds":22,"month":8,"timezoneOffset":-480,"year":118,"minutes":59,"time":1536908362000,"day":5},"useful":true,"displayUserRateLink":""},{"auctionPicUrl":"","userInfo":"","displayRatePic":"","dsr":0,"displayRateSum":0,"appendComment":null,"fromMemory":0,"picsSmall":[],"tmallSweetPic":"","rateDate":"2018-09-11 06:15:56","rateContent":"杩欑椋庢牸鐨勮。鏈嶏紝缁х画鏉ヤ竴浠躲€傛懜璧锋潵寰堣垝鏈嶏紝涓嶉敊锛?,"fromMall":true,"userIdEncryption":"","sellerId":3329658704,"displayUserLink":"","id":1016479648579,"aliMallSeller":false,"reply":"","pics":[],"buyCount":0,"userVipLevel":0,"auctionSku":"棰滆壊:娣辩伆鑹丙灏虹爜:M[缇庣増鍋忓ぇ]","anony":false,"displayUserNumId":0,"goldUser":false,"attributesMap":null,"tradeEndTime":{"date":5,"hours":12,"seconds":29,"month":8,"timezoneOffset":-480,"year":118,"minutes":38,"time":1536122309000,"day":3},"headExtraPic":"","aucNumId":0,"displayUserNick":"椋?**鏉?,"structuredRateList":[],"carServiceLocation":"","userVipPic":"","serviceRateContent":"","memberIcon":"","attributes":"","position":"","cmsSource":"澶╃尗","tamllSweetLevel":0,"gmtCreateTime":{"date":11,"hours":6,"seconds":56,"month":8,"timezoneOffset":-480,"year":118,"minutes":15,"time":1536617756000,"day":2},"useful":true,"displayUserRateLink":""},{"auctionPicUrl":"","userInfo":"","displayRatePic":"","dsr":0,"displayRateSum":0,"appendComment":null,"fromMemory":0,"picsSmall":[],"tmallSweetPic":"","rateDate":"2018-09-15 21:03:32","rateContent":"寰堝ソ鐪嬶紝涔熷疄绌匡紒","fromMall":true,"userIdEncryption":"","sellerId":3329658704,"displayUserLink":"","id":1017171014959,"aliMallSeller":false,"reply":"","pics":[],"buyCount":0,"userVipLevel":0,"auctionSku":"棰滆壊:榛戣壊;灏虹爜:S[缇庣増鍋忓ぇ]","anony":false,"displayUserNumId":0,"goldUser":false,"attributesMap":null,"tradeEndTime":{"date":7,"hours":7,"seconds":40,"month":8,"timezoneOffset":-480,"year":118,"minutes":50,"time":1536277840000,"day":5},"headExtraPic":"","aucNumId":0,"displayUserNick":"灏?**濮?,"structuredRateList":[],"carServiceLocation":"","userVipPic":"","serviceRateContent":"","memberIcon":"","attributes":"","position":"","cmsSource":"澶╃尗","tamllSweetLevel":0,"gmtCreateTime":{"date":15,"hours":21,"seconds":32,"month":8,"timezoneOffset":-480,"year":118,"minutes":3,"time":1537016612000,"day":6},"useful":true,"displayUserRateLink":""},{"auctionPicUrl":"","userInfo":"","displayRatePic":"","dsr":0,"displayRateSum":0,"appendComment":null,"fromMemory":0,"picsSmall":[],"tmallSweetPic":"","rateDate":"2018-10-23 19:47:50","rateContent":"璐ㄩ噺闈炲父濂斤紝涓庡崠瀹舵弿杩扮殑瀹屽叏涓€鑷达紝闈炲父婊℃剰,鐪熺殑寰堝枩娆紝瀹屽叏瓒呭嚭鏈熸湜鍊硷紝鍙戣揣閫熷害闈炲父蹇紝鍖呰闈炲父浠旂粏銆佷弗瀹烇紝鐗╂祦鍏徃鏈嶅姟鎬佸害寰堝ソ锛岃繍閫侀€熷害寰堝揩锛屽緢婊℃剰鐨勪竴娆¤喘鐗╄川閲忓緢濂斤紝甯屾湜鏇村鐨勬湅鍙嬩俊璧栵紟搴椾富鎬佸害鐗瑰ソ锛屾垜浼氬啀娆″厜椤剧殑锛庡彲涓嶅彲浠ュ啀渚垮疁鐐癸紟鎴戝甫鏈嬪弸鏉ヤ綘瀹朵拱銆備笉濂芥剰鎬濊瘎浠锋櫄浜嗭紝闈炲父濂界殑搴楀锛屼笢瑗垮緢娆紒涔版潵杩欎釜鏄€佷汉鐨勫ス寰堝枩娆㈠崠瀹剁殑璐村績璁╂垜鎰熷埌寰堟俯鏆栥€傚緢鐑儏鐨勫崠瀹讹紝涓嬫杩樻潵甯屾湜涓嬫杩樻湁鏈轰細鍚堜綔绁濅綘鐢熸剰鍏撮殕璐ㄩ噺闈炲父濂界湡鍑轰箮鎴戠殑鎰忔枡鍖呰闈炲父浠旂粏闈炲父鎰熻阿銆傜鐢熸剰鍏撮殕锛侊紒","fromMall":true,"userIdEncryption":"","sellerId":3329658704,"displayUserLink":"","id":1021728982469,"aliMallSeller":false,"reply":"","pics":[],"buyCount":0,"userVipLevel":0,"auctionSku":"棰滆壊:钘忛潚鑹丙灏虹爜:S[缇庣増鍋忓ぇ]","anony":false,"displayUserNumId":0,"goldUser":false,"attributesMap":null,"tradeEndTime":{"date":23,"hours":19,"seconds":7,"month":9,"timezoneOffset":-480,"year":118,"minutes":47,"time":1540295227000,"day":2},"headExtraPic":"","aucNumId":0,"displayUserNick":"瀵?**涓?,"structuredRateList":[],"carServiceLocation":"","userVipPic":"","serviceRateContent":"","memberIcon":"","attributes":"","position":"","cmsSource":"澶╃尗","tamllSweetLevel":0,"gmtCreateTime":{"date":23,"hours":19,"seconds":50,"month":9,"timezoneOffset":-480,"year":118,"minutes":47,"time":1540295270000,"day":2},"useful":true,"displayUserRateLink":""},{"auctionPicUrl":"","userInfo":"","displayRatePic":"","dsr":0,"displayRateSum":0,"appendComment":{"commentId":0,"days":1,"reply":"","commentTime":"2018-10-18 19:42:45","pics":["//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/i1/O1CN0120Dm3Aa6K2U9XBi_!!0-rate.jpg","//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/i3/O1CN0120Dm3H7e2fcHkVQ_!!0-rate.jpg"],"content":"琛ｆ湇濂界湅 瀹㈡湇鎺ㄨ崘鐨勭爜鏁颁篃寰堝噯 寮€蹇?},"fromMemory":0,"picsSmall":[],"tmallSweetPic":"","rateDate":"2018-10-18 15:06:30","rateContent":"琛ｆ湇鎸哄ソ鐨?,"fromMall":true,"userIdEncryption":"","sellerId":3329658704,"displayUserLink":"","id":1020974929870,"aliMallSeller":false,"reply":"","pics":[],"buyCount":0,"userVipLevel":0,"auctionSku":"棰滆壊:鐧借壊;灏虹爜:M[缇庣増鍋忓ぇ]","anony":false,"displayUserNumId":0,"goldUser":true,"attributesMap":null,"tradeEndTime":{"date":17,"hours":19,"seconds":44,"month":9,"timezoneOffset":-480,"year":118,"minutes":15,"time":1539774944000,"day":3},"headExtraPic":"","aucNumId":0,"displayUserNick":"鑿?**濠?,"structuredRateList":[],"carServiceLocation":"","userVipPic":"","serviceRateContent":"","memberIcon":"","attributes":"","position":"","cmsSource":"澶╃尗","tamllSweetLevel":0,"gmtCreateTime":{"date":18,"hours":15,"seconds":30,"month":9,"timezoneOffset":-480,"year":118,"minutes":6,"time":1539846390000,"day":4},"useful":true,"displayUserRateLink":""},{"auctionPicUrl":"","userInfo":"","displayRatePic":"","dsr":0,"displayRateSum":0,"appendComment":null,"fromMemory":0,"picsSmall":[],"tmallSweetPic":"","rateDate":"2018-09-05 13:28:55","rateContent":"灏辨槸鍐茬潃璐ㄩ噺鏉ョ殑","fromMall":true,"userIdEncryption":"","sellerId":3329658704,"displayUserLink":"","id":1015882409765,"aliMallSeller":false,"reply":"","pics":[],"buyCount":0,"userVipLevel":0,"auctionSku":"棰滆壊:鐧借壊;灏虹爜:S[缇庣増鍋忓ぇ]","anony":false,"displayUserNumId":0,"goldUser":false,"attributesMap":null,"tradeEndTime":{"date":5,"hours":13,"seconds":28,"month":8,"timezoneOffset":-480,"year":118,"minutes":28,"time":1536125308000,"day":3},"headExtraPic":"","aucNumId":0,"displayUserNick":"娴?**1","structuredRateList":[],"carServiceLocation":"","userVipPic":"","serviceRateContent":"","memberIcon":"","attributes":"","position":"","cmsSource":"澶╃尗","tamllSweetLevel":0,"gmtCreateTime":{"date":5,"hours":13,"seconds":55,"month":8,"timezoneOffset":-480,"year":118,"minutes":28,"time":1536125335000,"day":3},"useful":true,"displayUserRateLink":""},{"auctionPicUrl":"","userInfo":"","displayRatePic":"","dsr":0,"displayRateSum":0,"appendComment":null,"fromMemory":0,"picsSmall":[],"tmallSweetPic":"","rateDate":"2018-10-23 11:05:55","rateContent":"榛勮壊瀹炵墿杩樻槸寰堝ソ鐪嬬殑 搴椾富浜轰篃涓嶉敊","fromMall":true,"userIdEncryption":"","sellerId":3329658704,"displayUserLink":"","id":1021657538950,"aliMallSeller":false,"reply":"","pics":["//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/i2/O1CN0120tS5wWgHwLpCUR_!!0-rate.jpg"],"buyCount":0,"userVipLevel":0,"auctionSku":"棰滆壊:榛勮壊;灏虹爜:S[缇庣増鍋忓ぇ]","anony":false,"displayUserNumId":0,"goldUser":true,"attributesMap":null,"tradeEndTime":{"date":23,"hours":11,"seconds":24,"month":9,"timezoneOffset":-480,"year":118,"minutes":5,"time":1540263924000,"day":2},"headExtraPic":"","aucNumId":0,"displayUserNick":"y***1","structuredRateList":[],"carServiceLocation":"","userVipPic":"","serviceRateContent":"","memberIcon":"","attributes":"","position":"","cmsSource":"澶╃尗","tamllSweetLevel":0,"gmtCreateTime":{"date":23,"hours":11,"seconds":55,"month":9,"timezoneOffset":-480,"year":118,"minutes":5,"time":1540263955000,"day":2},"useful":true,"displayUserRateLink":""}],"searchinfo":"","from":"search","paginator":{"lastPage":1,"page":1,"items":14},"tags":[]}})';
$json = json_decode(substr($json,14,-1));
print_r($json);
```

Comment: в переменной $json у вас не json строка, json у вас начинается с {"rateDetail":... а заканчивается .."tags":[]}}, остальное лишнее. То есть именно такая строка должна получиться после обработки функцией substr

Comment: По этому я вырезаю лишнее функцией: `substr()`

Comment: почему отрезаете с 14, если у вас начало json на 10м?

Comment: Еще у вас в `"寰堣垝鏈 nice 瀹㈡湇鍛 灏辨槸鏈夌偣鍌 浜鸿繕铔ソ鐨?,` не хватает последней закрывающей кавычки.

Comment: ну вы в промежуточном шаге выведете что получилось после обработки функцией substr, там получается то что нужно или нет?

Comment: Думаю проблемы в кавычках.

Comment: @newProgrammer, у вас не только в кавычках проблема, еще со скобками есть проблема

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, как вариант, исключительно для вашего случая с помощью `str_replace` (*[см. демо](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3b2785a1095d1ca65ba51edef481b8d9d51a8950)*):

```
$string = str_replace(['?,"', '?}'], ['?","', '?"}'], substr($json, 10, -1));
print_r(json_decode($string, true));
```

Или с `preg_replace` ([*см. демо*](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/86d10b0caaa9b9374534a359b2f581a1a3e9913a)):

```
$string = preg_replace('/\?(?=(?:})?,\")/', '$1"', substr($json, 10, -1));
print_r(json_decode($string, true));
```

Comment: Спасибо за готовое решения.

Comment: @newProgrammer, всегда пожалуйста :)